# dask.ml.xgboost raises UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment

Tags: dask, xgboost, dask-distributed

I am using dask_xgboost and I don't understand the error stated in the subject. I have successfully trained a model and saved it with joblib.dump.

Later on, during the prediction step I use it like this:

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.distributed as ddst
from dask_jobqueue import PBSCluster
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask_xgboost as dxgb
import geopandas as gp
from sklearn.externals import joblib


def predict(zs_files: List[str], model_name: str, client) -> None:
    delayed_dfs = [dask.delayed(gp.read_file)(zsf) for zsf in zs_files]
    model = joblib.load(model_name)
    delayed_predictions = [
        dxgb.predict(client, model, df).to_parquet(f"{fn}_predicted.parquet")
        for df, fn in zip(delayed_dfs, zs_files)
    ]
    delayed_predictions.compute()
```

I read a set of GeoJSON files with geopandas and then just feed the model with them. I am using a client on a PBS cluster.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I wass missing a from_delayed call to transform the geopandas dataframe to a dask one:

```
dxgb.predict(client, model, dd.from_delayed(df))
```